# How to use routes with reactive websocketstream in vertx

Tags: websocket, rx-java2, vert.x

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    var router = Router.router(vertx).route("/entity/:id")
    vertx.createHttpServer()
        .websocketStream()
        .toObservable()
        .subscribe(sock -> sock.)
        .map(ServerWebSocket::toObservable)
```

I'm new to vert.x I've managed to create an observable socket, but I don't understand how to use routes and url route parameters with reactive version of API.

Answer (score 4):

Vert.x Web router deals with HTTP requests. You can use it to handle the `upgrade` to websocket request:

```
router.route("/entity/:id").handler(rc -> {
  String entityId = rc.pathParam("id");
  HttpServerRequest request = rc.request();
  ServerWebSocket webSocket = request.upgrade();
  webSocket.frameHandler(frame -> {
    webSocket.writeFrame(WebSocketFrame.textFrame("Pong " + entityId, true));
  });
  webSocket.accept();
});
```

Inside the router handler, you may retrieve path parameters with the `RoutingContext#pathParam` method.

Comment: Um, okay. What would be the analogue of `@PathParam` of `@ServerEndpoint`?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. You want to make it possible to upgrade the connection to a websocket but only if the endpoint is `/entity/:id`, correct ?

Comment: Yes, and if possible use this parsed `id`.

Comment: Thanks, but how to this with rx? As you can see from my code I'm using `Observable`